# Python - PyInstaller failed to execute pyi_rth_pyqt5plugins

Tags: python, qt, pyqt5, pyinstaller

I am trying to freeze a Python script into a .exe file using `PyInstaller`. Tried to run the script before freezing it, and found no error. However, after the script is frozen using `PyInstaller` it returns an error, Failed to execute script `pyi_rth_qt5plugins`.

[image: the error message when the program is ran]

If I check the WARNING message when the PyInstaller is running, I found no significant error message related to PyQt5, even all the hooks are loaded successfully. Here are the message.

```
25120 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
25120 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
25527 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.etree.cElementTree.py"...
25527 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pkg_resources.py"...
25542 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-distutils.py"...
25558 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-lib2to3.py"...
25573 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-numpy.core.py"...
25698 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-win32com.py"...
26370 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
26433 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
26433 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pytz.py"...
26667 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
26667 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
26745 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pythoncom.py"...
26949 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sysconfig.py"...
26949 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pywintypes.py"...
27199 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.Qt.py"...
27199 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-setuptools.py"...
27199 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-sqlite3.py"...
27292 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
27402 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtPrintSupport.py"...
27558 INFO: checking Tree
27558 INFO: Building Tree because out00-Tree.toc is non existent
27558 INFO: Building Tree out00-Tree.toc
27589 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
27620 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
27636 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_qt5.py'
27636 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py'
27652 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pkgres.py'
27652 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_win32comgenpy.py'
...
27761 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
27855 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
27964 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
28042 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
28121 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
28246 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
28324 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qwindows.dll
28402 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtga.dll
28496 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtga.dll
28574 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtga.dll
28667 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
28761 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
28839 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
28933 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
29011 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
29089 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qtiff.dll
29183 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
29277 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
29355 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
29433 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
29527 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
29636 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
29730 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qoffscreen.dll
29839 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qicns.dll
29918 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qicns.dll
29996 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qicns.dll
30105 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qwbmp.dll
30199 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qwbmp.dll
30277 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qgif.dll
30371 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qgif.dll
30496 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qgif.dll
30574 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qwebp.dll
30668 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qwebp.dll
30746 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qwebp.dll
30824 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qwebp.dll
30918 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
30996 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
31090 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
31168 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
31246 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qjpeg.dll
31355 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qsvg.dll
31449 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qsvg.dll
31543 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\iconengines\qsvgicon.dll
31621 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\iconengines\qsvgicon.dll
31715 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qminimal.dll
31840 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\platforms\qminimal.dll
31918 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qico.dll
32012 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\imageformats\qico.dll
32105 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\printsupport\windowsprintersupport.dll
32188 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\Qt\plugins\printsupport\windowsprintersupport.dll
32407 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35\DLLs\_multiprocessing.pyd
32548 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtCore.pyd
32641 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtCore.pyd
32719 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtCore.pyd
32813 WARNING: lib not found: api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll dependency of C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\PyQt5\QtCore.pyd
```

Lastly, if I check on the warned txt file in `build` folder, I found this message.

```
missing module named 'PyQt5.sip' - imported by C:\Users\Arnold\Envs\pdproduction\lib\site-packages\pyinstaller-3.3.dev0+82fb738-py3.5.egg\PyInstaller\loader\rthooks\pyi_rth_qt5plugins.py
```

Currently I am using `Windows 10`, `Python 3.5.1`, `pandas 0.19.2`, `PyQt5 5.8.1`, `Qt 5.8.0`, `SIP 4.19.1`, and `PyInstaller 3.3dev`. The attempts that I have tried so far:

1. Downgrade the PyQt5 version to lower version, however, it crashed every time I executed the script. Tried with PyQt5 5.6 and PyQt5 5.7. Therefore, I stick to PyQt5 5.8
2. Uninstall and install SIP, does not work.

Any suggestions will be much appreciated. Thanks!

P.S. If I try to freeze the program using Anaconda, then everything works great. However, the size of the exe file is huge! It is almost 200Mb! But if I try to freeze it in pure Python, no Anaconda, then the file size is acceptable, around 37Mb. Therefore, I prefer to freeze it not in Anaconda.

Comment: Finally I made it. Seemly the newest SIP is not supported yet by the PyInstaller, thus, it returns an error. I downgraded the SIP to 4.18, then it worked fine.

Comment: arnold: That's good to know! We have been dealing with this problem also. Can you write this as an answer here below as well? Thanks!